# How do I push unique copies of array into another array?

Tags: arrays, ruby

I'm trying to push subsets into an array:

```
def subsets(arr)
    subsets = [[]]
    temp_arr = []
    i = 0
    while i < arr.length
        temp_arr << arr[i]
        subsets << temp_arr
        p subsets
        i+=1
    end
    return subsets
end
```

My results look like this:

```
[[], ["a"]]
[[], ["a", "b"], ["a", "b"]]
[[], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"], ["a", "b", "c"]]
```

Why is it that every time I push the temp_array to the subset array, the previous result of pushing temp_array also changes?

Is there a way I can push the unique instances of temp_array and keep it in that state?

Also, can anyone give me a hint as to how I can get all subsets from an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
subsets << temp_arr
```

`temp_arr` references to the actual `Array` object. After this, both the element appended to `subsets` and `temp_arr` reference to the same object.

If this is not what you expected, use `dup` to gets its copy:

```
subsets << temp_arr.dup
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're pushing the same object, `temp_arr`, onto `subsets`.

Ruby generally does not copy data, it passes around references to objects.  `subsets << temp_arr` puts a reference to `temp_arr` onto `subsets`, not whatever happens to be in `temp_arr` at the moment.

```
subsets[0] -> temp_arr
subsets[1] -> temp_arr
subsets[2] -> temp_arr
```

To avoid this, you want to make a [copy of `temp_arr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Object.html#method-i-clone) and push that onto `subsets`.

```
while i < arr.length
    temp_arr << arr[i]
    subsets << temp_arr.clone
    p subsets
    i+=1
end
```

As an aside, your loop can be written better using [`each`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-each).

```
arr.each { |element|
    temp_arr << element
    subsets << temp_arr.clone
    p subsets
}
```

Or avoid the temp variable entirely by using an [array slice](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D).

```
arr.each_index { |idx|
    subsets << arr[0..idx]
    p subsets
}
```